# Can I use cardboard as a dust cover for a video card?

Tags: graphics-card

I’ve been looking around online for an answer about the compatibility between cardboard and PCB for the purpose of a dust cover. Found nothing, so I came here.

The reason I’m thinking about this is because of two factors: one, that my video card’s PCB is exposed and there is no backplate as some do these days, and two, my house is overly obscenely dusty.

I end up dusting my computer every week or so as I fear the graphics card, above all else, would short circuit somewhere on the exposed microchips and solder leads from the backplate.

I was thinking of custom-cutting a chunk of ~1/8th piece of cardboard for the video card backplate, leaving room for under the video card core, and leaving it on top of the video card. As reference, I know that placing a Motherboard on the box it came in is usually good as an anti-static test bench/workspace, but I wanted to make sure it was okay in this regard.

**Edit**

My graphics card is a Sapphire Radeon HD-6970, and as clarification, when I talk about the backplate, I talk about the exposed part of the video card opposite to the fan. This isn’t just limited to just any video card.

Further shown as this:

[image: Example 1]

And a “backplate” that I want to DIY would be like this:

[image: Example 2]

And, unfortunately, I cannot use Dust Filters. Dust filters have had a terrible history in my house, causing more problems than posing solutions. Let’s just say more than one of our computers had overheating problems making the end result the removal of the filters. In other words, dust filters last a whole week before needing cleaning in my experience.

Comment: Most graphic cards have an exposed backside.  You are worrying over something that isn't an issue.

Comment: If you are really that worried.  Here is some [relevant](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1658509/sapphire-amd-radeon-7970-vapor-3gb-backplate.html) information that might be helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound Probably. Honestly, I worry about these kind of things, regardless of the severity. Due to my OCD, I couldn't help but wonder if I could DIY something for my GPU. anything, really.

Comment: Any DIY solution would likely be a worst experience then your experience with dust filters.

Comment: @Ramhound ....Hmm, you might be right. But you could put your answer up anyhow; it might be useful for someone else! ;) (someone else that views this, anyhow)

Comment: I submitted a comment because what I said wasn't an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably **not a good idea**.

As your graphic card came open, it's cooling probably designed to work so,  cover may cause it overheating, also the other parts don't like dust too.

Instead you should use some filter at your fans, like e.g. [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FJU8BC), or just make your [own one](http://www.techradar.com/news/computing/how-to-keep-dust-out-of-your-pc-663270)